# C++, program thinks i dont have a main function when i do and is giving "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable error

Tags: c++, linker

I am new to c++ and coding on a MAC, I just switched over from windows. I installed the brew package manager by writing the following command in my terminal.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

and with brew I installed g++ and mingw-w64 by writing the following commands in my terminal

```
brew install g++
brew install mingw-w64
```

I proceeded to install code runner and the C++ extension in VS code then wrote the following code which is giving me and error and I have no clue how to fix this.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_main", referenced from:
        implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbols not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error
```

this was the code I wrote

```
// Your First C++ Program

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to use Xcode, the native Apple IDE.

Comment: "wrote the following code" Where's the code, and how do you compile it?

Comment: n. 'pronouns' m.  I've updated it so the code may be seen

Comment: @PranayKatnawer You didn't show the command line you invoked to get the error. Most likely, that command is missing `main.cc` of `main.o`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian How can I fix this?

Comment: We cannot fix what we cannot see. Please show the command you line you invoked.